# How can I perform a binary search on a list of objects in Scala

Tags: scala, big-o, binary-search, scala-collections

```
case class Employee (id: Int, name : String, age : Int)

// Added four emplyees emp1, emp2 emp3, emp4 to the list like below::

val emp1 = Employee(101, "name1", 101)
val emp2 = Employee(102, "name2", 102)
val emp3 = Employee(103, "name3", 103)
val emp4 = Employee(104, "name4", 104)

list = scala.List(emp1, emp2, emp3, emp4)
```

I would like search for an employee by its name in the list using BINARY SEARCH, and retrieve that employee object..

Note: the search complexity should be O(logn) and we should NOT use any map for the purpose.

something like

```
val emp = list.binarysearch("name2")
println("the returned employee's age: ", emp.age) //should print 102
```

Any help would be appreciated.!

Comment: This question looks like you are asking us to implement binary search for you. [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Binary search is a well known topic and if you put some effort, you should be able to find enough resources online to understand this.

Comment: nope, this is not I am asking. i do not want someone to implement any search mechanism for me, i myself can do that.. All i need to know : is there any existing api in scala to perform binary search on a sorted list.. and retrieve the object from the list if the match is found.

Comment: All binary search implementations involve random index access for `x'th` index on the list/array and keep on determining the next `x'th` index to look at. Basically `O(log n)` time-complexity of binary search requires random index access to be `constant` time. But `list.get(i)` for any `list: List` in Scala is `linear` time which mean that `O(log n)` time complexity can not be achieved for `List` in Scala.

Comment: I think you overlooked my requirement, I am already saying my list is already sorted.. keep your thought according to that.. I am not naive to all of this detail.. I understand that very very well.. Please read well my first comment you'll get to know my need..

Comment: The `get` function of a `List` is `O(n)`. Binary Search is not a sensible algorithm to run on a `List`. If you use `Array` instead, binary search works fine, and the code looks basically the same as any other language.

Comment: A Scala list is a linked list, as is in any other functional language. Binary search would take longer than a linear scan and find. You say you understand this “_very very well_”, but clearly you don’t, otherwise you’d not be arguing with the people trying to help.

Answer (score 6):

[Searching](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.0-M3/src/library/scala/collection/Searching.scala#L61-L99) provides binary search but you need an Indexed sequence, not a linear one (ie. `List`), as others have explained - otherwise you can still use `search` but you get linear O(n) behaviour rather than O(Log n).

You say you want to search on name, so you need to sort on name otherwise your results could be inconsistent. You should research `scala.math.Ordering`

So if you can convert your list to an array then you can do this.

```
case class Employee (id: Int, name : String, age : Int)
val emp1 = Employee(1, "Jane Doe", 45)
val emp2 = Employee(2, "Jon Doe", 54)
val emp3 = Employee(3, "Ada Lovelace", 38)
val emp4 = Employee(4, "Charles Babbage", 36)
// convert to an array
val employees = List(emp1, emp2, emp3, emp4).toArray

// define your ordering
import scala.math.Ordering
implicit object NameOrdering extends Ordering[Employee] {
  def compare(a:Employee, b:Employee) = a.name compare b.name
}

// now sort
import scala.util.Sorting
Sorting.quickSort(employees)(NameOrdering)
```

And then.

```
import scala.collection.Searching._

// If the element is found its index is returned
scala> val result = employees.search(emp3)
result: collection.Searching.SearchResult = Found(3)
```

To retrieve the element use the `insertionPoint` method on the result.

```
scala> employees(result.insertionPoint)
res6: Employee = Employee(3,Ada Lovelace,38)
```

If the element is not found then the index of its insertion point in the sorted sequence is returned.

```
val emp5 = Employee(5, "Grace Hopper", 34)     // not added

scala> employees.search(emp5)
res2: collection.Searching.SearchResult = InsertionPoint(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can never do a binary search on scala List() in O(log n)** as we cannot discard half the list at a time, we'd have to traverse till the mid point for that. However it can be done with the Array. In Scala, **you can create an implicit class to have a binarySearch() method on any Array[String] instance**

```
  implicit class StrArrayOps(strArray: Array[String]) {
    @scala.annotation.tailrec
    private def bs(arr: Array[String], s: Int, e: Int, str: String): Option[Int] = {
      if (e<s) {
        None
      } else {
        val m = (s+e)/2
        val mid = arr(m)
        if (mid == str) {
          Some(m)
        } else {
          if (str.compareTo(mid) > 0) {
            bs(arr, m+1, e, str)
          } else {
            bs(arr, 0, m-1, str)
          }
        }
      }
    }

    //returns None if str not found in the strArray
    //returns Some(i) where i is the index of str in the strArray
    def binarySearch(str: String): Option[Int] = bs(strArray, 0, strArray.length-1, str)
  }
```

You can use it as below

```
scala> val a = Array("name1", "name2", "name3")
a: Array[String] = Array(name1, name2, name3)

scala> a.binarySearch("name2")
res20: Option[Int] = Some(1)

scala> a.binarySearch("name1")
res21: Option[Int] = Some(0)

scala> a.binarySearch("name3")
res22: Option[Int] = Some(2)

scala> a.binarySearch("name34")
res23: Option[Int] = None
```